# How can I install H5P SCORM libraries?

Tags: 7, theming

The subject says it all. I am attempting to install H5P SCORM libraries in an install of Drupal 7.59 and running into a roadblock: None of what I am reading—or understanding—is clear about how to install the libraries. I am attempting this on macOS High Sierra under MAMP 4.5 (PHP 7.1.12) and MAMP 3.5.2 (PHP 5.6.10). Apache permissions are fine as far as I can see, FWIW and other temp files and uploads work fine on this setup.

I have installed the following two modules in Drupal:

- [H5P](https://www.drupal.org/project/h5p): The core H5P module.
- [H5P SCORM/xAPI](https://www.drupal.org/project/h5p_scorm): The H5P SCORM API.

And on the module’s install page I have activated all three modules connected to them:

- **H5P (7.x-1.35)**
- **H5P Editor (7.x-1.35)**
- **H5P SCORM (7.x-2.4)**

But when I go to install the libraries… I just can’t seem to get them to upload without some error happening such as a problem expanding the archive into the `temp/` directory and such. The weird thing is temp direcroures are clearly created, but there is no content in them.

I have even followed the “[Better Install Instructions](https://www.drupal.org/project/h5p_scorm/issues/2954423)” that appear here as a contributed “issue” but with no luck.

The libraries in question are as follows:

- [H5PEditor SCORM](https://github.com/pavloshevchuk/h5p-editor-scorm)
- [H5P SCORM/xAPI](https://github.com/pavloshevchuk/h5p-scorm)

Do the decompressed files need to have a directory name such as `H5PEditor.ScormFile.h5p` or `H5P.Scorm.h5p`? Because if I simply rename the files, the created directory is still `h5p-editor-scorm-master` and `h5p-scorm-master`.

The tangential question is… Is there simply a way I can just physically place files in the correct directory structure user `libraries/`? Or must it be installed via the administration interface? It seems to me if I could just drop those files in, Drupal—and the H5P modules—should be able to see them, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this page about how to manually construct H5P packages](https://h5p.org/hello-world-h5p-package) and follow the same process for each repo.

You need to download the repo Zip file. Decompress into a temp directory. Delete the `LICENSE`, `README.md`, and `.gitignore` files

Create a new folder to hold the rest of the files like `library.json`, CSS, JS For the H5P editor, name it `H5PEditor.ScormFile`. For the `h5p-scorm-master`, use `H5P.Scorm`:

Outside of the new folder, create an `h5p.json` file.

For the `H5PEditor.ScormFile`, use this:

```
{
  "title": "H5PEditor.ScormFile",
  "language": "en",
  "author": "Pavlo Shevchuk",
  "license": "cc-by-sa",
  "preloadedDependencies": [
    { "machineName": "H5PEditor.ScormFile", "majorVersion": 1, "minorVersion": 0,"patchVersion": 8, }
  ],
  "mainLibrary": "H5PEditor.ScormFile",
}
```

for the `H5P.Scorm`, use:

```
{
  "title": "SCORM/xAPI",
  "language": "en",
  "license": "cc-by-sa",
  "preloadedDependencies": [
    { "machineName": "H5P.Scorm", "majorVersion": 1, "minorVersion": 1, "patchVersion": 16, }
  ],
  "mainLibrary": "H5P.Scorm",
  "embedTypes": ["div"]
}
```

Now Zip up the right `h5p.json` folder and the `H5PEditor.Scormfile` or and the other with `H5P.Scorm` directory. Zip compress each, naming the editor file `H5PEditor.ScormFile.h5p` and the second library `H5P.Scorm.h5p`.

#### Creating `H5PEditor.ScormFile.h5p`.

So create Zip file renamed to `H5PEditor.ScormFile.h5p`. Inside of that you have a folder named `H5PEditor.ScormFile` with contents of the Git repo, `https://github.com/pavloshevchuk/h5p-editor-scorm`, specified files removed. You also create a `h5p.json` file with the code provided. Place it in the Zip file but outside the `H5PEditor.ScormFile` directory.

```
H5PEditor.ScormFile.h5p
├── H5PEditor.ScormFile
│   ├── library.json
│   ├── scripts
│   │   ├── scormFile.js
│   │   └── scormFileUploader.js
│   └── styles
│       └── scormFile.css
├── H5PEditor.ScormFile.h5p
```

#### Creating `H5P.Scorm.h5p`.

Create a second Zip file renamed to `H5P.Scorm.h5p`. Inside of that you have a folder named `H5P.Scorm` with contents of the Git repo: `https://github.com/pavloshevchuk/h5p-scorm`, specified files deleted. Place the `icon.svg` file in a directory called `content`, inside the Zip file. You also create a `h5p.json` file with the code provided. Place it in the Zip file but outside the `H5P.Scorm` directory. The Zip file contains this structure:

```
H5P.Scorm.h5p
├── content
│   └── icon.svg
├── h5p.json
├── H5P.Scorm
│   ├── css
│   │   └── scorm.css
│   ├── js
│   │   ├── api
│   │   │   ├── api_1_2.js
│   │   │   ├── api_2004.js
│   │   │   ├── datamodel.js
│   │   │   ├── debug.js
│   │   │   └── flash_detect.js
│   │   └── scorm.js
│   ├── library.json
│   └── semantics.json
```

You should now have two H5P files and you will now be able to update them at the H5P admin libraries page:

```
admin/content/h5p
```

Here's a repo containing the files I made following these instructions:
https://github.com/jackrabbithanna/h5p-scorm-libraries

Comment: I know I tried a couple of times before I got it right and didn't get that error. You could look in the site's public files directory and see if a file H5P.Scorm.h5p already exists there, and the delete it, then try the upload again

Comment: If there's an entry in the file_managed database table with a value for the uri column that contains the file name for the .h5p file, try deleting that row in the database.

Comment: I provided the answer for the original question, now you ask a new one. Should be a separate post

Comment: @JakeGould I cleaned up a bunch of comments.  Continuing to add to your question after answers have come isn't a great for for any SE site.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions is a starting point for the reasoning behind this.

Comment: Okay, this has been solved on my side. [Details here on the other question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/263273/36892), but on a clean install of Drupal 7.59 I was able to track down the issue being connected to a missing Font Awesome h5p specific library. Once I rolled my own H5P module for Font Awesome and get that installed, everything else worked fine. Thanks for the help and patience on this!

Comment: Fantastic! I must have already had the font awesome library from other H5P content types I had installed. Would you like to fork my github repo of the h5p files and make a PR, adding your font awesome library, so that people in the future can just get down to business?

Comment: @jackrabbithanna Feel free to add it on your own. I’m happy you have helped. The reason I won’t do a pull request is that my Github profiles is far more public and directly connected to me than my login here. So I don’t want to mix the two; I like to divide things that way. So feel free to credit “JakeGould on Stack Exchange” if you wish. Also, [check the bottom of my answer on that other question for a Bash script I quickly put together](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/263273/36892) to make life easier getting this stuff setup.