# Unable to install the “H5P.Scorm.h5p” library: “The uploaded file was not a valid h5p package”

Tags: 7

[Thanks to jackrabbithanna’s help on this other question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/263140/36892) I seem to be 1/2 way to getting H5P related libraries installed in my Drupal 7.59 install. I am attempting this on macOS High Sierra under MAMP 4.5 (PHP 7.1.12) and MAMP 3.5.2 (PHP 5.6.10).

But like I said, I am 1/2 way there; not fully there. I am able to get the `H5PEditor.ScormFile (1.0.8)` library installed, but not `H5P.Scorm (1.1.16)`.

The libraries in question are as follows:

- [H5PEditor SCORM](https://github.com/pavloshevchuk/h5p-editor-scorm)
- [H5P SCORM/xAPI](https://github.com/pavloshevchuk/h5p-scorm)

To help this process, I have now devised a bit of a Bash scripting process to get the `h5p` packages built from the source GitHub repos. Here is what I do…

#### The `H5PEditor.ScormFile (1.0.8)` Bash dance:

```
cd ~/Desktop/

git clone https://github.com/pavloshevchuk/h5p-editor-scorm 

cd ~/Desktop/h5p-editor-scorm

find . -type f \( -name '.DS_Store' -o -name '.gitignore' -o -name 'LICENSE' -o -name 'README.md' \) -exec rm {} \;
find . -type d -name '.git' -exec rm -rf {} \;

mkdir H5PEditor.ScormFile && mv {scripts,styles,*.json} H5PEditor.ScormFile

echo '{
  "title": "H5PEditor.ScormFile",
  "language": "en",
  "author": "Pavlo Shevchuk",
  "license": "cc-by-sa",
  "preloadedDependencies": [
    {
      "machineName": "H5PEditor.ScormFile",
      "majorVersion": 1,
      "minorVersion": 0,
      "patchVersion": 8
    }
  ],
  "mainLibrary": "H5PEditor.ScormFile",
}' > h5p.json

zip -r ../H5PEditor.ScormFile.h5p *
```

#### The `H5P.Scorm (1.1.16)` Bash dance:

```
cd ~/Desktop/

git clone https://github.com/pavloshevchuk/h5p-scorm

cd ~/Desktop/h5p-scorm

find . -type f \( -name '.DS_Store' -o -name '.gitignore' -o -name 'LICENSE' -o -name 'README.md' \) -exec rm {} \;
find . -type d -name '.git' -exec rm -rf {} \;

mkdir H5P.Scorm && mv {css,js,*.json} H5P.Scorm
mkdir content && mv icon.svg content

echo '{
  "title": "SCORM/xAPI",
  "language": "en",
  "license": "cc-by-sa",
  "preloadedDependencies": [
    {
      "machineName": "H5P.Scorm",
      "majorVersion": 1,
      "minorVersion": 1,
      "patchVersion": 16
    }
  ],
  "mainLibrary": "H5P.Scorm",
  "embedTypes": [
    "div"
  ]
}' > h5p.json

zip -r ../H5P.Scorm.h5p *
```

And with those two things done I now have two H5P files ready to go: `H5PEditor.ScormFile.h5p` and `H5PEditor.ScormFile.h5p`.

But while installing `H5PEditor.ScormFile.h5p` proceeds as expected, the same can’t be said for `H5PEditor.ScormFile.h5p`. I get the following Drupal system information message:

> For security reasons, your upload has been renamed to H5P.Scorm_.h5p.

Followed by this “great news”:

> The uploaded file was not a valid h5p package

Screenshot attached below. Any insight is appreciated.

[image: Screensnot of the “H5P.Scorm.h5p” library failing to install as expected.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Short Answer

Font Awesome (4.5.4) libraries needed to be explicitly installed for H5P so that Scorm (1.1.16) can be installed. Details on how that was done near end of answer.

---

#### Long Answer

Happily, I was able to self-solve this. Starting with a fresh, clean, 100% new install of Drupal 7.59 I went ahead with this process again. Getting `H5PEditor.ScormFile (1.0.8)` installed was fine—as before on a more established Drupal 7.59 install—but ran into the same exact issue with `H5P.Scorm (1.1.16)`… But on this clean install I did get a major clue via more details in error reporting; screenshot below but the text reads:

> “Missing required library FontAwesome 4.5”

[image: FontAwesome H5P Error]

I took this error to mean that the Drupal module and related libraries for Font Awesome were not installed and that is why the “The uploaded file was not a valid h5p package.” error came up.

So I went ahead and did that—and installed Font Awesome 4.7 libraries—screenshot below:

[image: Drupal 7.59 Installed Modules]

Tried installing `H5P.Scorm (1.1.16)` again… And again, the same message:

> “Missing required library FontAwesome 4.5” message.

So I took this all to mean that H5P needed it’s own library install of Font Awesome, Googled and [found this H5P related Font Awesome repo](https://github.com/h5p/font-awesome).

Great! So now [learning what I learned previously in this other answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/263140/36892), I figured out how to create my own `H5P.FontAwesome.h5p` library, which WORKS GREAT! Screenshot below to show the process did work and I was able to get `H5P.Scorm (1.1.16)` installed once the H5P specific Font Awesome library was installed as well:

[image: All SCORM stuff installed after Font Awesome libaray was set]

And to make everyone’s life easier—especially mine—I created a fairly simple Bash script that allows me to automatically create the `H5PEditor.ScormFile.h5p`, `H5P.FontAwesome.h5p` and `H5P.Scorm.h5p` libraries on my macOS machine; see below for source code. Just save it as a Bash file named something like `build_h5p_scorm_libs.sh` and give yourself execute permissions via `chmod u+x build_h5p_scorm_libs.sh` and you are good to go.

Library installation order should be as follows:

- `H5PEditor.ScormFile.h5p`
- `H5P.FontAwesome.h5p`
- `H5P.Scorm.h5p`

Genuinely hope this helps someone in the future!

```
#/bin/bash

################################################################################
# Build the H5PEditor.ScormFile H5P file.
################################################################################

# Go to the Desktop.
cd ~/Desktop/

# Clone the repo.
git clone https://github.com/pavloshevchuk/h5p-editor-scorm

# Go into that cloned repo.
cd ~/Desktop/h5p-editor-scorm

# Clean up cruft that is not needed for the H5P file.
find . -type f \( -name '.DS_Store' -o -name '.gitignore' -o -name 'LICENSE' -o -name 'README.md' \) -exec rm {} \;
find . -type d -name '.git' -exec rm -rf {} \;

# Create the library directory and copy files into it.
mkdir H5PEditor.ScormFile && mv {scripts,styles,*.json} H5PEditor.ScormFile

# Create the 'h5p.json' file.
echo '{
  "title": "H5PEditor.ScormFile",
  "language": "en",
  "author": "Pavlo Shevchuk",
  "license": "cc-by-sa",
  "preloadedDependencies": [
    {
      "machineName": "H5PEditor.ScormFile",
      "majorVersion": 1,
      "minorVersion": 0,
      "patchVersion": 8
    }
  ],
  "mainLibrary": "H5PEditor.ScormFile",
}' > h5p.json

# Now Zip that all up into a compressed `.h5p` archive like this.
zip -rq ../H5PEditor.ScormFile.h5p *

################################################################################
# Build the H5P.FontAwesome H5P file.
################################################################################

# Go to the Desktop.
cd ~/Desktop/

# Clone the repo.
git clone https://github.com/h5p/font-awesome

# Go into that cloned repo.
cd ~/Desktop/font-awesome

# Clean up cruft that is not needed for the H5P file.
find . -type f \( -name '.DS_Store' -o -name '.gitignore' -o -name 'LICENSE' -o -name 'README.md' \) -exec rm {} \;
find . -type d -name '.git' -exec rm -rf {} \;

# Create the library directory and copy files into it.
mkdir FontAwesome && mv {*.css,*.otf,*.eot,*.svg,*.ttf,*.woff*,*.json} FontAwesome

# Create the 'h5p.json' file.
echo '{
  "title": "FontAwesome",
  "language": "en",
  "license": "cc-by-sa",
  "preloadedDependencies": [
    {
      "machineName": "FontAwesome",
      "majorVersion": 4,
      "minorVersion": 5,
      "patchVersion": 4
    }
  ],
  "mainLibrary": "FontAwesome"
}' > h5p.json

# Now Zip that all up into a compressed `.h5p` archive like this.
zip -rq ../H5P.FontAwesome.h5p *

################################################################################
# Build the H5P.Scorm H5P file.
################################################################################

# Go to the Desktop.
cd ~/Desktop/

# Clone the repo.
git clone https://github.com/pavloshevchuk/h5p-scorm

# Go into that cloned repo.
cd ~/Desktop/h5p-scorm

# Clean up cruft that is not needed for the H5P file.
find . -type f \( -name '.DS_Store' -o -name '.gitignore' -o -name 'LICENSE' -o -name 'README.md' \) -exec rm {} \;
find . -type d -name '.git' -exec rm -rf {} \;

# Create the library directory and copy files into it.
mkdir H5P.Scorm && mv {css,js,*.json} H5P.Scorm

# Create the content directory and copy files into it.
mkdir content && mv icon.svg content

echo '{
  "title": "SCORM/xAPI",
  "language": "en",
  "author": "Pavlo Shevchuk",
  "license": "cc-by-sa",
  "preloadedDependencies": [
    {
      "machineName": "H5P.Scorm",
      "majorVersion": 1,
      "minorVersion": 1,
      "patchVersion": 16
    }
  ],
  "mainLibrary": "H5P.Scorm",
  "embedTypes": [
    "div"
  ]
}' > h5p.json

# Now Zip that all up into a compressed `.h5p` archive like this.
zip -rq ../H5P.Scorm.h5p *
```